# I just want to list ONLY the child categories, but not grandchildren

Tags: categories

I have this code that can list all child and grandchild categories, but I just need ONLY child categories, not grandchildren. How can I fix it?

```
function get_category_root_id($cat)
{
$this_category = get_category($cat);   
while($this_category->category_parent) 
{
$this_category = get_category($this_category->category_parent);
}
return$this_category->term_id; 
}
```

Can you help me out , thanks !

Comment: this does not list anything, it simply finds the root category, i.e. the top level ancestor of the category being passed in $cat

Answer (score 0):

worked it out already.

```
<?php wp_list_categories("child_of=&depth=1&hide_empty=0&title_li="); ?>
```

put the above code at the proper place in the files category.php or archive.php and modify "depth=0" to "depth=1". It works.

Thank you all.